# How to write static class holder idiom singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I have to write this code  in lazy initialization "static class holder idiom singleton" pattern

```
 public class DateComparator{
    private static DateComparator instance = null;
    public static  DateComparator getInstance()
    {
       if(instance == null)
          instance = new DateComparator();
       return instance;
    }
 }
```

This is my changed code:

```
public class DateComparator{
    private static DateComparator container = null;
    private static class DateComparatorHolder {
        private static DateComparator instance=createInstance();
    }
    private static DateComparator createInstance() {
        if(container == null)
            //container = new DateComparator();
        return new DateComparator();
    }
    public static DateComparator getInstance()
    {       
        return DateComparatorHolder.instance;
    }
```

Comment: Simple: either use java enums (guaranteed to be correct regarding thread safety) or read and apply: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `container` variable or `createInstance()`:

```
public class DateComparator{
    private static class DateComparatorHolder {
        private static final DateComparator instance= new DateComparator();
    }

    public static DateComparator getInstance()
    {       
        return DateComparatorHolder.instance;
    }
}
```

That's all.